# Java error with creating new file

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I have a little problem in java. I have Created a new File
and that file is in the class called `mainPlayerVariables` and its variable is `public static File savePlayerCoins = new File("c:\\Games\\Coin_Clicker\\saves\\pc.txt");` But in the `mainGame` script where my JFrame is i added a JButton and this onClick function on it:

```
mainPlayerVariables.playerCoins++;
lblCoins.setText("x" + mainPlayerVariables.playerCoins);

try {
                BufferedWriter bwSaveCoins = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(mainPlayerVariables.savePlayerCoins));
                bwSaveCoins.write(mainPlayerVariables.playerCoins);
                bwSaveCoins.close();

                mainPlayerVariables.savePlayerCoins.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                mainPlayerVariables.savePlayerCoins.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Now I don't know why Java displays an error to the bufferedWriter and Create new file code.

Please help if you know. Thank you.
Here is the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\Games\Coin_Clicker\saves\pc.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
at mainGame.mainGamePlay$2.mouseReleased(mainGamePlay.java:82)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If I made a mistake in the file option, please help me correct it. :)

Comment: It clearly says FileNotFoundException right ? "The system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: yes, but why. I have the code getParentFile().mkdirs();

Comment: Your code makes no sense whatsoever. You should be calling `mkdirs()` *first*`, *then* `new FileWriter()`, and writing and closing, and not calling `createNewFile()` *at all.*

Comment: yes, I know, i found that out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Um, guys I found out why, no need to answer. :) by the way Thanks all.

I have placed the `mainPlayerVariables.savePlayerCoins.getParentFile().mkdirs();`
Code at the wrong place.

this is the correction:

```
mainPlayerVariables.savePlayerCoins.getParentFile().mkdirs();
try {
            BufferedWriter bwSaveCoins = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(mainPlayerVariables.savePlayerCoins));
            bwSaveCoins.write(mainPlayerVariables.playerCoins);
            bwSaveCoins.close();

            mainPlayerVariables.savePlayerCoins.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Just so you know, your `createNewFile()` call won't do anything, because the file already exists at that point.

Comment: So you should remove it.